# LM565/NE565 Spice modeling in Orcad PsPice/Proteus/Multisim

Tags: proteus, pll, pspice, multisim

"Q: Display the outputs specified in the following figures in the simulation software and the results. That's it."

I have trouble getting the answer from this circuit.

When I realized that this chip was not in the software, I guessed to myself that this chip may have been modeled by someone and it is on the Internet. None of these three programs has this part, but I was able to find a PDF that the PSpice simulation model has this piece for Orcad software but I do not know how to give it to the software.

So far I have only edited the models, but I do not know how to make a new model.

[image]
[image]

These are the questions that the college teacher asked us, and he only wants the answer to this circuit.I know that a chip like 4046 is better for that, and maybe if it were not for the coronavirus, I could have built this circuit in the lab and saved myself from this.

Comment: I suggest you ask a clear and obvious question.

Comment: What questions has the teacher asked you?  There are none in your post.

Comment: Well Q: Show the output of the following circuit waveform in the software!
That is, I have to show the output of the points marked on the figure to the teacher in the simulator
The output waveform of the same circuit, which in the second form of a variable resistor can have a voltage-controlled oscillator, that's it!

Comment: Of course, what the teacher asked us is not one or two questions, and there are about 15 questions, but this circuit is enough for me to work and I can do the rest myself. I apologize if something went wrong and I did not ask my question clearly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I can see, what you want is  way to import spice model in pspice.
You will have to either find a readymade model or import one yourself from a online source or directory.

[This might be what you are looking for][1]

Failing that, you might want to replace the IC with a 4046 or 7446 IC.
As 565 PLL is no longer being manufactured and is only seen in textbooks.
[1]: [How to import PSPICE Model into Orcad Capture?](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/92848/how-to-import-pspice-model-into-orcad-capture)