# How to install the downloaded model file to pspice?

Tags: simulation, spice, pspice, orcad, library

I am newbie in pspice.I am using 17.4 version of Orcad.I have downloaded mosfet model from a site.Model includes this files: "device.lib" , "device.olb" and  "device.ind" .I want to simulate this device.What is the meaning of files with these extensions? (.lib,.olb,.ind)How can I install these files to pspice?

edit:I have 3 different file types.And I want to learn the meanings of these file extensions.I haven't .mod and opj file like other topic.my file extensions are different other topic.I've already seen that topic, but it didn't solve my problem.Other topic is very old.(7 years)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to import PSPICE Model into Orcad Capture?](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/92848/how-to-import-pspice-model-into-orcad-capture)

Comment: @Bimpelrekie No,this question is very old.7 years ago.I have 3 different file types.And I want to learn the meanings of these file extensions.I haven't .mod and opj file like other topic.my file extensions are different other topic.I've already seen that topic, but it didn't solve my problem.

Comment: I took a quick look at the following document and it at least explains what the `.lib`, `.olb`, and `.ind` files are.  https://www.parallel-systems.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2020/02/Using_Spice_Models_in_OrCAD_PSpice_from_vendor_models.pdf